# I can't export the array I have created in one of my react components

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, export

I have been trying to export this array to dynamically render on another page (based on input from fakeApi) within my app and can't get it to work. I'm new to react and not sure if this is the correct way to achieve what I want.

Basically, I would like the full api (yet to create just using fake one for testing) to appear on one page (which is working). Then based on the information received from the array show which networks are down on the homepage of my app. Any help is much appreciated. Please see code.

```
import NetworkComponent from './NetworkComponent';

let fakeApi = [
    {
      key: 1,
      HostIPAddress: "1.1.1.1",
      HostFriendlyName: "BBC",
      HostMonitored: "down",
      HostType: "VPN"
    },
  
    {
      key: 2,
      HostIPAddress: "8.8.8.8",
      HostFriendlyName: "johnlewis.co.uk",
      HostMonitored: "ok",
      HostType: "VPN"
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      HostIPAddress: "2.3.4.5",
      HostFriendlyName: "hello.co.uk",
      HostMonitored: "down",
      HostType: "VPN"
    },
  ];
  
  const NetworkScan = () => {
          
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Network Monitor</h1>
        <div className="container mx-auto">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            {fakeApi.map(service => (
              <NetworkComponent key={service.key} service={service} />
              
            ))}
              
          </div>
         

          {fakeApi.forEach((service) => {
    if(service.HostMonitored === "down") {
        
     let networkErr = [];
    networkErr.push(service.HostMonitored, service.HostFriendlyName, service.HostIPAddress)
    console.log(networkErr);
    }
     })};       
          
        </div>
      </div>
  
    );
  };


  
export default NetworkScan;
```

Comment: How have you tried to export the array? I don't see any export calls on that array

Answer (score 0):

You can export it as object `export { fakeApi }` and import it as `import { fakeApi } from '../..'`

Answer (score 0):

Put that array object into a `.json` file (i.e. fakeApi.json) and import it like `import fakeApi from './fakeApi.json'` wherever you want.